# Is there something like for i in range(length) in PHP?

Tags: php, python, range

In python we have:

```
for i in range(length)
```

What about in PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Straight from the [docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Comment: One caveat: Python's `range(0, 13)` or `range(13)` is equivalent to PHP's `range(0, 12)`

Comment: php range generates a sequence, either increasing or decreasing from first to last: range(5,0) will give you 5,4,3,2,1,0. Python generates only an increasing series and first to end. range(5,0) in python is empty!

Answer (score 5):

Old fashioned `for` loops:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < length; $i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Or foreach using the [range function](http://php.net/range):

```
foreach (range(1, 10) as $i) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Here's a python compliant range generator

```php
foreach ($x in xrange(10)) {
  echo "$x ";
} // expect result: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

function xrange($start, $limit = null, $step = null) {
    if ($limit === null) {
        $limit = $start;
        $start = 0;
    }
    $step = $step ?? 1;
    if ($start <= $limit) {
        for ($i = $start; $i < $limit; $i += $step)
            yield $i;
    } else
        if ($step < 0) 
            for ($i = $start; $i > $limit; $i += $step)
                yield $i;
}
```

*mostly cribbed from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php*

#### Notes

- It will not automatically step backwards (like python, unliike PHP)
- It can accept 1, 2 or 3 arguments (like python)
- It will count to $limit - 1 (like python, unlike PHP)
- If your arguments are silly, you get no results (like python)
- It doesn't store the range in memory (unlike PHP) so you can have HUGE ranges

Answer (score 1):

`for ($i = 0; $i < LENGTH_GOES_HERE; $i++) { ... }`

or

`foreach (range(0, LENGTH_GOES_HERE - 1) as $i) { ... }`, cf. [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).

Comment: the `foreach` line should use `LENGTH_GOES_HERE - 1`

Comment: @intgr I'm offsetting on the `low` instead.

Comment: @intgr But you're right, I see. We want `$i` to have the same values as in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a range function in php, you can use like this.

```
foreach( range(0,10) as $y){
    //do something
}
```

but unlike python, you have to pass 2 parameters, range(10) will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Generates the digits in base 10.
// array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
foreach (range(0, 9) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// range(start, end, step=1): array
//
foreach(range(0,5) as $i) echo $i; // 012345
// but unlike python you also can range letters 
foreach(range('a','z') as $l) echo $l; //abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
// or floating
foreach(range(0.1, 0.2, 0.01) as $f) echo "$f; "; //0.1; 0.11; 0.12; 0.13; 0.14; 0.15; 0.16; 0.17; 0.18; 0.19; 0.2;
// negative step work with letters
foreach(range('z','a',-1) as $l) echo $l; // zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
// and dont stuck if invalid negative step just ignore and use abs(step) value
foreach(range(1,10,-2) as $i) echo $i; // 13579
// but throw fatal if step exceed the specified range, so, test if step in range before using
foreach(range(1,10,-20) as $i) echo $i; 
// Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: range(): Argument #3 ($step) must not exceed the specified range in /home/user/scripts/code.php:12
// Stack trace:
// #0 /home/user/scripts/code.php(12): range(1, 10, -20)
// #1 {main}
// thrown in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 12
?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).